# Installing older versions of Emacs (19.34)

Tags: emacs, solaris

I am having some trouble installing an older version of emacs (19.34) to run an old script. Currently, I have downloaded the source code and tried to compile but I am getting some error which I don't seem to understand (there are some previous errors with line endings too, but they can be fixed).

I am first running the ./configure script, then running

```
gmake && gmake install
```

I am getting this error

```
Producing `src/paths.h' from `src/paths.in'.
src/paths.h is unchanged
Producing `src/paths.h' from `src/paths.in'.
src/paths.h is unchanged
cd lib-src; gmake all  \
  CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-g -O' CPPFLAGS='' \
  LDFLAGS='' MAKE='gmake'
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/user/b/user1/emacs-19.34/lib-src'
gmake[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/user/b/user1/emacs-19.34/lib-src'
cd src; gmake all  \
  CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-g -O' CPPFLAGS='' \
  LDFLAGS='' MAKE='gmake'
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/user/b/user1/emacs-19.34/src'
cd ../lwlib/; gmake -w
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/user/b/user1/emacs-19.34/lwlib'
gmake[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/user/b/user1/emacs-19.34/lwlib'
CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-g -O' MAKE='gmake'
"C_SWITCH_X_SITE=-I/usr/openwin/include"
/bin/sh: C_SWITCH_X_SITE=-I/usr/openwin/include: not found
gmake[1]: *** [really-lwlib] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/user/b/user1/emacs-19.34/src'
gmake: *** [src] Error 2
```

I have checked that /usr/openwin/include is present in the server, and have manually added /usr/openwin/include to PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Somehow, the Makefile is not picking it up.

The server config is SunOS 5.10, Generic January 2005. I do not have sudo access, but I have manually set the install path to my local home directory.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Any suggestions that I could install Emacs 19.34 on the server without installing from source would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the double quotes around this line coming from?

```
"C_SWITCH_X_SITE=-I/usr/openwin/include"
```

It looks like /bin/sh is complaining about this entire line "not found", rather than setting an environment variable as that line seems to be intended to do.

If this line is not something you set yourself, then trying a different shell (`SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash gmake` for example) might work.

Comment: In fact, it looks like `gmake` is spawning a `sh` process to try to execute `"C_SWITCH_X_SITE=-I/usr/openwin/include"`.  I'd think posting the actual `configure` command itself is important.